# HTML Email template - mso conditional statement

Tags: html, html-email, email-templates

I'm working with an HTML email template for a project. Everything works great on Gmail, Yahoo, and Outlook web email client, except for the Outlook desktop app v16.0, which I have a spacing rendering issue. I used mso conditional statement to target this specific version. But it doesn't seem to work the margin-bottom that I added in   and wrapped in mso statement didn't acknowledge. Any idea how to fix this?.

[Email rendered in Gmail and Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqGYk.png)

Here is my code:

```html
<tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:25px;">
  <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;font-weight: 400 !important;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:560px" valign="top">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;font-weight:400 !important;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
          <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
            <!-- ADDED MSO CONDITIONAL STATEMENT FOR OUTLOOK ONLY-->

            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                   <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;Margin-bottom:8px;">
             <![endif]-->

              <!-- END  -->
              
              <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
              <p style="Margin:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:400 !important;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333;">You&rsquo;re just one step away from being</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is your snippet correct? The text in it is different from your screenshot "one step away from being" vs "one step away".  Also the spacer you are adding as a td which would be a spacer next to that text on the side, not below it

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not valid with two  after eachother on outlook. And as @jmona789 says, a td you make it on the side not above. Maybe this would work better with a new

```html
<tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:25px;">
        <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"
            style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;font-weight: 400 !important;" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                    <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:560px" valign="top">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"
                            style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;font-weight:400 !important;"
                            width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <!-- ADDED MSO CONDITIONAL STATEMENT FOR OUTLOOK ONLY-->

                                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                    <td height="8" style="height: 8px; font-size: 0px; line-height:0px">&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                 <![endif]-->

                                <!-- END  -->
                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">


                                    <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;">
                                        <p
                                            style="Margin:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:400 !important;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333;">
                                            You&rsquo;re just one step away from being</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done some typo here, You have made first letter capital of **margin** property, which is setting paragraph margin to 0. Make this **margin** property all lowercase. See typo error in code below:

`<p style="Margin:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:400 !important;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#333;">You&rsquo;re just one step away from being</p>`

Replace all **Margin** to lowercase **margin** to fix this issue.